# Advise about putting together a custom footer in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm putting together a custom footer in wordpress but I only want to show only the pages with sub-pages. For the moment I'm hard coding it but I'm trying to find a nicer way for maintenance sake. Any advice? Thanks.

------- EDIT ---------

OK, this is what I have according to the code: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

I just included in my footer.php

```
<?php wp_list_pages('child_of = 7'); ?>
```

but it is showing everything when I only want to show the child of ID=7. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: do you have some code ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales, Ok, I just added some code.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of=20&depth=1'); ?>
```

No idea but `child_of=7` it is not same as `child_of = 7`. The `child_of = 7` was returning all the pages.